# Power BI calculated column Indicating any row with same ID contains specific text

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm trying to capture if an ID (represents a user) completes the entirety of a form. This is measured by the row stating "Confirmation".

Due to other data needed, I also can't just have the row with "Confirmation" say "Yes". I need all rows with that ID to state the status as "Yes".

Below is what I'm looking for:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**FYI:** I originally used to duplicate the table, filter for rows that say "Confirmation", and then dedupe the ID's to get a list to relate to, however, there is a formatting issue that occurs when I do that now, so I need alternative methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the number of matches of `Confirmation` for the current `ID` value and then check if that number is greater than 0. (Note: This works as a calculated column, not as a measure.)

```
Result =
IF (
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            Table1,
            Table1[ID] = EARLIER ( Table1[ID] )
                && Table1[Action] = "Confirmation"
        )
    ) > 0,
    "Yes",
    "No"
)
```

Here's another way to do the same thing using a different method of counting:

```
Result =
IF (
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( Table1[ID] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[ID] ),
        Table1[Action] = "Confirmation"
    ) > 0,
    "Yes",
    "No"
)
```

Comment: Holy cow - solved all my problems as if it were nothing haha. Thanks a ton!